# Can we enable Game Center for particular version?

Tags: ios, game-center

I am new to Game Center, after gone through Game Center in&out. I have some questions in my mind, I need clarification from any of you guys:

1) Can we enable Game Center for particular app version,(ie) previous app version 1.0 doesn't have Game Center feature, so I like to enable Game Center for 2.0 app version. So, my question is, if I enable Game Center for app version 2.0, whether it can affect previous app version 1.0?

2) Why most of the app not providing Game Center login feature inside their app, instead of login via Game Center feature?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you can integrate Game Center in the same app for its next version. Not a problem at all. Your user will get notification that update is available once they updated they will have feature. And you previous version will also work fine if somebody don't want to update.

2) If your app is game Center enabled that means, it has to communicate with it for many times in many ways. eg. to get score, update score, get achievements, get leader board and  challenges. All of the above feature requires game center authentication to proceed further. Most of the app (even the one i created) needs game center login at start after that it works smoothly. It is better to ask for authentication using login via game Center.

Comment: Thanks abdus ... But, one more small doubt, while enabling Game center whether it would ask, "which version you want to apply"?

Comment: you should enable game Center and push new build. All will be working as described